# Terraform Lambda heredoc not resolving inline function variables

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, heredoc

My interpolated variable, with or with out the ${} chars, will not resolve to the Terraform referenced value.  My code looks like this:

```
data "archive_file" "lambda_zip_file_int" {
  type        = "zip"
  output_path = "/tmp/lambda_zip_file_int.zip"
  source {
    content  =  <<EOF
    'use strict';
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
      ...
      var params = {
        foo: ${aws_cognito_user_pool.my_pool.id}
      }
      ...
        callback(null, event);
      });
    };
EOF
    filename = "foo.js"
  }
}
```

The lambda function creates correctly, but

```
      var params = {
        foo: ${aws_cognito_user_pool.my_pool.id}
      }
```

is saved in my function as a literal, with no substitution of the actual value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi. This question seems exactly same as before. Was the last question resolved? Also if you go back one step, and just try to resolve a simple variable, `${var.test}` does it work?

Comment: I referenced the wrong var in my last question, so resubmitted with the correct exact issue. Will try your var.test suggestion and get back to you, ty for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [template expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html) you shared here seems that it would create invalid JavaScript syntax, because substituting a Cognito pool id directly into that location would produce something like this:

```
  var params = {
    foo: us-west-2:11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
  }
```

A more robust way to get this result would be to make use of [Lambda environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html) so that the JavaScript code in your Lambda function can be entirely static but can access the Cognito pool id from an environment variable passed in when you declare the function later:

```
  source {
    content  =  <<EOF
    'use strict';
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
      ...
      var params = {
        foo: process.environment.COGNITO_POOL_ID
      }
      ...
        callback(null, event);
      });
    };
EOF
    filename = "foo.js"
  }
```

Notice that the above is just the normal way to access environment variables from a NodeJS program, and not something special to Terraform.

When you declare the Lambda function using [`aws_lambda_function`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function) you can then pass in the final concrete value for that environment variable, which allows you to change it later without rebuilding the code package:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "example" {
  # ...

  environment {
    variables = {
      COGNITO_POOL_ID = aws_cognito_user_pool.my_pool.id
    }
  }
}
```

---

Although I would suggest avoiding dynamic code generation wherever possible, you could also potentially make your original example valid JavaScript syntax by relying on the fact that the JSON encoding of strings is also a valid JavaScript encoding of strings:

```
      var params = {
        foo: ${jsonencode(aws_cognito_user_pool.my_pool.id)}
      }
```

This should also produce a working result, but means that the Cognito pool ID is embedded in your function's source code where later changes to it will require rebuilding the source code package.

```
  var params = {
    foo: "us-west-2:11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"
  }
```

Comment: The jsonencode method didn't work, it ended up putting a literal jsonencode(... string into the lambda.  The environmental variable method did work, thanks!